# Xamarin: Can we have multiple different resource files in one library project

Tags: xamarin, resources, project

I want to have single library to host other libraries AppResources file.

If i have two projects and one language project which will host two Resources of those two projects.

Eg. Login and Scanner Projects, and one single project which have both Projects' resources.

If I have Login.AppResources and Scanner.AppResources, can i placed them into one project.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can i mean in the end they are just static classes in the background

Comment: I thought so too. but i only have one set as public and other still in internal eventhough i already change to PublicResx..... as well

Comment: So what problem are you facing exactly?

Comment: i am facing the generated class still using internal modifier instead of public. only one resource file was set to public